# How do I rewrite Adobe Photoshop plugins for Adobe Lightroom?

Tags: plugins, adobe, photoshop, lightroom

Are Adobe's plugin architectures for Photoshop and Lightroom related in any way? If I have source code for a plugin, that works with PS 3.0-CS3 as well as PS Elements 6.0 can I use it with Lightroom directly? If not, what would I have to modify?

Comment: Hey guys, I am a programmer and I am asking what to (re)program here. I had to rephrase my original question to point that out so please spare me the "unrelated" and "duplicate" tags.

Answer (score 1):

No.. lightroom plugins are written in the scripting language lua, photoshop plugins are written in C++.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by kasperjj, the Lightroom plugins are written in Lua so there is not a direct way to convert something from Photoshop over to Lightroom. Additionally, as per the [Adobe Lightroom Developer Center](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshoplightroom/), the only features that are extendable in the current SDK are the export functionality, metadata, and web engine functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Rob, the Lightroom SDK does not expose any interface that allows manipulations of the image files themselves. Partly this is because Lightroom is a non-destructive editor. None of the edits made in its Develop module are applied to the original image file; they are applied to the file generated when the image is exported, printed, or used in a web gallery.

That said, there are examples of export plugins that manipulate the image *after* Lightroom has finished applying its adjustments. In principle, it would be possible to create a host application that loaded a Photoshop plugin and applied it during Lightroom export. It might even be possible to use Photoshop itself as that host application...